# Mailgun X-Mailgun-Variables are not sent in webhooks for email received

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, mailgun

I have a rails app and I'm sending email through Mailgun smtp

```
mail(
  to: @user.email,
  subject: 'Notification From ME',
  'X-Mailgun-Variables' => { subscription_id: subscription.id }.to_json
)
```

The header is showing in google full email view (original message) as

```
X-Mailgun-Variables: {"subscription_id":2}
```

When I reply to the email the webhook notification that I receive docent have the variables in the payload.

Should this header be visible to the clients ?

How should I setup or send my variables to mailgun so I can receive them when email relay webhook is triggered ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#attaching-data-to-messages):

> When using variables, the `X-Mailgun-Variables` header will be
> included in the MIME of the delivered email. This means that
> recipients who receive emails when variables are used WILL be able to
> see the variables if they view the MIME headers.

It sounds like what you're really looking for is **Tagging** however, that is not supported via the SMTP method you appear to be using. However, if you use Ruby then there is a SDK package that will enable you to send messages with tagging. You can find the Ruby library for Mailgun on Github at: https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-ruby